# Wrong value returned from stored procedure output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return 2 output parameters from a stored procedure to c#, but the thing is, the parameter @Student_number always returns 1 instead of the string that it should return. I've tried doing it directly in the sql management studio, but it returns the values correctly.

```
setCommand("sp_EnrollStudent");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class_id", st.classId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_id", st.studentId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearLevel_id",st.yearLevelId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear_id", st.acadYearId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment_type", st.paymentType);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount_id", st.discountId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", st.balance);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_amount", st.totalAmount);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmlData", xml);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isEnrolled", st.isEnrolled);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_number", " ");
cmd.Parameters["@Student_number"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Return_code", 0);
cmd.Parameters["@Return_code"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
returnVal = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@Return_code"].Value.ToString());
Form_RegistrationDetails_View.studentNumber = cmd.Parameters["@Student_number"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: did you try to run the stored procedure directly from ssms and check what you get? also, as a side note, the `sp_` prefix is not a good idea. Microsoft use this prefix for system procedures. use a different prefix (`stp_` is very popular).

Comment: At first sight that looks ok. There is probably a problem in the stored procedure. Check that, and if you can't find anything edit the question to add the SP's code. (Also, add a comment so anyone who has added a comment will be notified.)

Comment: `AddWithValue` you are passing a string with length 1. Does it then assume `varchar(1)`?

Comment: Curious - why make Student_number an input/output param if you are just passing an empty string? Why not declare it a straight-up output param?

Comment: I've fixed it. The problem was the size of the varchar it returns, Thanks @Martin for the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use AddWithValue. You should be explicit in your datatypes. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Also, you should avoid the use the sp_ prefix (or even better avoid prefixes entirely). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!